# C int print formatting problems

Tags: c, printing, integer, format

I'm trying to print out time in like

hours:mins:secs

so if it was 8am, 12 mins, 34 seconds have this

08:12:34

but I keep getting

8:12:34

or

_8:12:34

Is there a way to make sure there is a '0' in front?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, use

```
%02d:%02d:%02d
```

as your `printf` format output. (You didn't say what output method you were using, so I am assuming stdio and `printf`.)